# Notification when firebase is updated?

Tags: android, http, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a chat application where I want the a user to get a notification when the other user sends a message. I've heard you can do it with a js script and followed the google guidelines but I'm confused where am I actually writing the script? Do I have to do the free trial for the google firebase environment?

Comment: Take a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Comment: Also have a look at this: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html and https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens

Comment: I used the command line to install jsNode and initialize firebase but I'm so confused where am I typing the js script?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:-

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(reference)

 FirebaseArray snapshots = new FirebaseArray(ref);

 snapshots.setOnChangedListener(new FirebaseArray.OnChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(EventType type, int index, int oldIndex) {
                switch (type) {
                    case Added:                       
                        break;
                    case Changed:                        
                        break;
                    case Removed:                        
                        break;
                    case Moved:                        
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: This won't work if the app is closed though will it?

Comment: If app is closed what you want to do with update details it won't show on any UI, but if still required put the code inside Service and it will get the update callback